# Receiving Error "imported content is empty" when using ImportHTML

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the following formula (have tried using a bunch of different table numbers) and am receiving the "imported content is empty" error. Any ideas as to why or possible solutions?

```
importhtml("https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/pointspread/1st-quarter/",
           "table",
           1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only what you see in the picture can be scraped

[image]

use **`IMPORTXML`**

find data you need with `INDEX` -ing

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/pointspread/1st-quarter/";
 "//*")
```

or point to specific **`div`** like:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/pointspread/1st-quarter/";
 "//div")
```